# XmlSerializer - serialize property-member as attribute

Tags: c#, xml, properties, serialization

I am trying to serialize (`XmlSerializer`) all members of an inherided property as attributes.

**Both classes:**

```
public class Tree
{
    public Point Location { get; set; }
}

public class AppleTree : Tree
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int FruitCount { get; set; }
}
```

**Main Program:**

```
AppleTree appleTree = new AppleTree
{
    Location = new Point(10, 20),
    FruitCount = 69
};
// Serialize ...
```

**Now I get this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AppleTree FruitCount="69">
  <Location>
    <X>10</X>
    <Y>20</Y>
  </Location>
</AppleTree>
```

But I want all members of `Location` as attributes of `AppleTree`.
**Like that:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AppleTree FruitCount="69" X="10" Y="20" />
```

**I know, I could to something like:**

```
public class Tree
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Point Location { get; set; }
}

public class AppleTree : Tree
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int FruitCount { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int X
    {
        get { return Location.X; }
        set { Location = new Point(value, Location.Y); }
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Y
    {
        get { return Location.Y; }
        set { Location = new Point(Location.X, value); }
    }
}
```

But I don't want to have duplicates of all properties (This is just a simple example).

So is there another solution? Perhaps with attributes of `XmlSerializer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you bring X and Y as properties to your base class you get the desired behavior:

```
public class Tree
{

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Point Location { get; set;}

    [XmlAttribute]
    public double X { 
        get { return Location.X;} 
        set { Location = new Point(value, Location.Y); }
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public double Y { 
        get { return Location.Y;} 
        set { Location = new Point(Location.X, value); }
    }
}

public class AppleTree : Tree
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int FruitCount { get; set; }
}
```

Serializes for me as follows:

> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
>   `<AppleTree xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`
>    `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`
>      `X="10"`
>      `Y="20"`
>      `FruitCount="69" />`